# How to extract specific lines from a file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I am working on a script which should extract specific kind of users and its corresponding uidNumber from a command result and output it into a file. The sample command result is:

```
dn: uid=test_user_2,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
cn: test_user_2
uid: test_user_2
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 400
homeDirectory: /home/test_user_2
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fSo=

dn: uid=test_user_3,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
cn: test_user_3
uid: test_user_3
uidNumber: 500
gidNumber: 400
homeDirectory: /home/test_user_2
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fSo=

dn: cn=test_group_3,ou=Group,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
cn: test_group_3
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/test_user_3
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fSo=
```

I want to print all users with `"ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot"` and `uidNumber` with 10000 to 60000

I have already extracted lines with `"ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot"` however, i have no idea how to extract its corresponding `uidNumber`

I used the the command below:

```
$LDAP_command | grep "dn: uid=.*,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot" > ldapsearch_extracted.txt
```

Expected output should be like this:

```
dn: uid=test_user_2,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
uidNumber: 10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -n '/^\(dn\|uidNumber\):/H;/^$/ba;$ba;bb;:a;x;/uidNumber: [1-5][0-9]\{4\}\b/p;:b' <file.txt 

dn: uid=test_user_2,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
uidNumber: 10000
```

or

```
sed -n '/^\(dn:.*ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot\|uidNumber:\)/H;/^$/ba;$ba;bb;:a;x;/uidNumber: [1-5][0-9]\{4\}/p;:b' <file.txt
```

Explanation:

Could by written:

```
sed -n '
    /^\(dn\|uidNumber\):/H;
    /^$/ba;
    $ba;
    bb;
   :a;
    x;
    /uidNumber: [1-5][0-9]\{4\}\b/p;
   :b
  ' <file.txt
```

- Search for `^dn:` or `^uidNumber`, then add to *hold space*
- On empty lines `^$` branch to label `:a`
- On last line branch to label `:a`
- branch to label `:b`
- label **`:a`**

  - swap current *pattern space* (empty line) with *hold space*
  - if `uidNumber: [1-5][0-9]\{4\}` (from `10000` to `59999` included), then print
- label **`:b`** (loop to next line)

Or

```
sed -n '
     /^dn:.*ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot/H;
     /^uidNumber:/H;
     /^$/ba;
     $ba;
     bb;
    :a;
     x;
     /uidNumber: [1-5][0-9]\{4\}\b/p;
    :b
   ' <file.txt
```

#### With explicit conditions:

```
sed -n '
    /^\(dn\|uidNumber\|gidNumber\):/H;
    /^$/ba;
    $ba;
    bb;
  :a;
    x;
    /uidNumber: [1-5][0-9]\{4\}\b/{
        /ou=People/{
            /fsFragmentId=Security/{
                /fsClusterId=ClusterRoot/{
                    p;
                }
            }
        }
    };
  :b
    ' <file.txt
```

This will

- Store dn, uidNumber and gidNumber in hold space,
- On lastline or empty line, if uidNumber: [1-5][0-9]{4} (from 10000 to 59999 included), then

  - if ou=People, then

    - if fsFragmentId=Security, then

      - if fsClusterId=ClusterRoot, then print.

The main advantage of doing this way is to ensure this work with another variables order on `dn` line.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what i want to output. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I edit this part: `/^\(dn\|uidNumber\):/H;` to be like:
`/^\(dn: cn\|gidNumber\):/H;` 

so that I could also print Groups? I have edited my example on the question

Comment: @EdMorton uidNumber between 10000 and 60000!

Comment: @EdMorton just add `/^gidNumber/H;` somewhere,in 1st 2 lines (before branch `:b`).

Comment: @EdMorton Ok I've missed `$` to mark end of line, or `\b` to mark bounding, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146541/discussion-between-f-hauri-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 0):

You can try following command,

```
awk '
  /ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot/{print} 
  /uidNumber/{if ($2>=10000 && $2<=60000)print}
' file
```

Comment: Hi, this works! however, it prints all the users regardless of  `uidNumber`, I am hoping to print users with `uidNumber 10000 - 60000`

Comment: @NicaRivera No problem, I modify the answer to limit the uidNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have name=value pairings in your input, by far the clearest, simplest and most extensible approach is to start by creating an array that contains that mapping (`f[]` below) and then you can just access values by their name:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS=OFS="\n"; ORS="\n\n" }
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        name = value = $i
        sub(/:.*/,"",name)
        sub(/^[^:]+:+[[:space:]]*/,"",value)
        f[name] = value
    }
}
(f["dn"] ~ /ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot/) &&
        (f["uidNumber"]+0 >= 10000) && (f["uidNumber"]+0 <= 60000) {
    print p("dn"), p("uidNumber")
}
function p(n) { return n ": " f[n] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
dn: uid=test_user_2,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
uidNumber: 10000
```

Obviously whatever else you want to do to implement other conditions and/or print other fields in whatever order you like is completely trivial just by following the above structure.

Want to print the `gidNumber`? Just change the print statement from:

```
    print p("dn"), p("uidNumber")
```

to:

```
    print p("dn"), p("uidNumber"), p("gidNumber")
```

Want to print the 2nd record? just change

```
(f["dn"] ~ /ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot/) &&
        (f["uidNumber"]+0 >= 10000) && (f["uidNumber"]+0 <= 60000) {
```

to:

```
NR==2 {
```

Want to print records where `cn` == `uid`? Change the above to:

```
f["cn"] == f["uid"] {
```

Want to print records where `uidNumber` is not populated? Change the above to:

```
f["uidNumber"] == "" {
```

That and anything else you might want to do with any combinations of the fields is completely obvious, trivial, and consistent.

The above is run on the file below, you do not need a preceding `grep` or anything else.

```
$ cat file
dn: uid=test_user_2,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
cn: test_user_2
uid: test_user_2
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 400
homeDirectory: /home/test_user_2
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fSo=

dn: uid=test_user_3,ou=People,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
cn: test_user_3
uid: test_user_3
uidNumber: 500
gidNumber: 400
homeDirectory: /home/test_user_2
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fSo=

dn: cn=test_group_3,ou=Group,fsFragmentId=Security,fsClusterId=ClusterRoot
cn: test_group_3
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/test_user_3
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fSo=
```